# NULL handling enhancement in PL/SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query doesn't list out all records that contain `null` value in `WFD_DETECTION_EPA` when we pass in some value in `S1_WFD_OPERATION_CODE` variable. Only records with `WFD_DETECTION_EPA` is not `null` appear in the result.

How to enhance this query?

```
           AND UPPER (FD.WFD_DETECTION_EPA) LIKE
                      '%'
                   || CASE
                         WHEN LENGTH (S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA) > 0
                         THEN
                            UPPER (S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA)
                         ELSE
                            '%'
                      END
                   || '%'
            AND UPPER (FD.WFD_OPERATION_CODE) LIKE
                      '%'
                   || CASE
                         WHEN LENGTH (S1_WFD_OPERATION_CODE) > 0
                         THEN
                            UPPER (S1_WFD_OPERATION_CODE)
                         ELSE
                            '%'
                      END
                   || '%'
```

Comment: Perhaps you simply want something similar to `WHERE (UPPER(FD.WFD_DETECTION_EPA) LIKE '%' || UPPER(S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA) || '%' or LENGTH(S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA) < 1) and ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition combined with OR

```
AND (UPPER (FD.WFD_DETECTION_EPA) LIKE
                      '%'
                   || CASE
                         WHEN LENGTH (S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA) > 0
                         THEN
                            UPPER (S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA)
                         ELSE
                            '%'
                      END
                   || '%' OR FD.WFD_DETECTION_EPA IS NULL) -- this
            AND UPPER (FD.WFD_OPERATION_CODE) LIKE
                      '%'
                   || CASE
                         WHEN LENGTH (S1_WFD_OPERATION_CODE) > 0
                         THEN
                            UPPER (S1_WFD_OPERATION_CODE)
                         ELSE
                            '%'
                      END
                   || '%'
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is more complicated than necessary.  Although by default Oracle treats empty strings and `NULL` as the same, string concatenation ignores `NULL` values.  So you can use:

```
(UPPER(FD.WFD_DETECTION_EPA) LIKE '%' || UPPER(S0_WFD_DETECTION_EPA) || '%' OR
 FD.WFD_DETECTION_EPA IS NULL
) AND
(UPPER(FD.WFD_OPERATION_CODE) LIKE '%' || UPPER(S1_WFD_OPERATION_CODE) || '%'
)
```

That is, the `CASE` expression is unnecessary.